# How to make Tradingview indicator to not change Auto price scale?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I always turn on the Auto scale Button in the right bottom of Tradingview and when I put the Round number horizontal line indicator, it want to show all 4 or 6 lines, so it kind of scale out and zoom out the chart, so all lines could be seen. I mean [THIS](https://www.tradingview.com/v/ZN56FUFR/) indicator.

how can I change the code somehow to make the indicator just put the lines on the chart and not change my price zoom scale?

I made the scale to **scale.none**, but it was showing lines in the wrong place on chart when I was moving around on chart.

`indicator("Round Numbers", shorttitle="Round Num", overlay=true, scale=scale.none)`

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart scale settings cannot be changed from Pine Script, but you can toggle the *"Scale Price Chart Only"* option so that the chart is scaled according to the OHLC symbol data and ignores the plots from the scripts:

[image]